# Same App Appears Twice in Apple Health Sources since migrating to SwiftUI App Lifecycle

Tags: swiftui, healthkit, watchos

I recently updated an Apple Watch App from the app + extension lifecycle to the SwiftUI lifecycle.

Or to put it another way, the bundle Ids have changed so that:

Before

- `com.myapp`
- `com.myapp.watchkitapp`
- `com.myapp.watchkitapp.extension`

After

- `com.myapp.paddlelogger`
- `com.myapp.watchkitapp`

For me everything works great, but we have multiple reports of people seeing two versions of the app in the Apple Health Sources

[image: Screenshot of multiple app sources in Apple Health]

This means there are two "sources" of data and two sets of permissions. In the past we just had one set of permissions.

It also means we have trouble reading data on the iPhone app that was recorded on the watch app.

`HKSource.default().bundleIdentifier` is
`com.myapp` on iPhone and
`com.myapp.watchkitapp` on Apple Watch

That must be part of the issue(?).

Is this something I've done wrong? I can't find any docs on migrating from from the legacy Extension style to the new SwiftUI Lifecycle

Comment: Can you raise a ticket with Apple TSI (DTS team) and they should be able to help you. You will be entitled to 2 tickets per year, you can buy more if you exhaust them

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: When reading Apple Health data in the app I now have to check for both bundle ids to distinguish data from my app vs that from 3rd party apps.

From speaking to other developers, this is not the only app that appears twice in Health, so I am assuming this is an Apple issue.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? Only I'm seeing it too and it's causing issues with my app users. Have also put Feedback in (FB11704560, submitted 4 months ago) and have a TSI request in. Thanks

Comment: Hi Simon, no update :( my work around is in place and I haven't really done anything with it since, although I spoke to someone who works for a big fitness app yesterday and they said they are seeing the same issue. please do update here if you get anything back from Apple

Comment: Will do. Only update is I also put in a TSI request and got rejected as it's a "known issue" so at least they are aware.

Comment: it's a shame you have to use TSI's get apple to confirm the existence of a bug (or really communicate with you at all), but better than nothing I suppose

Comment: Whats the current status of this issue. I recently moved to a single watxhKit app and users on WatchOS 8 are reporting this issue. It seems like it may have been resolved in WatchOS 10 but a workaround will still be needed for earlier versions of WatchOS which store their permsiiosns seperately and also store their workouts with the Watch App bundleID as the source (meaning the phone cant ready them with `HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: .default())`

Comment: @bencallis I don't have any new information :( if you find anything please share :)

Comment: From what I can see from users complaints it is an issue on the latest version of WatchOS 8. I've not had any reports of it on WatchOS 9 yet so it is likely to get fixed in a fairly early point release of watchOS 9. I'm having to ship a workaround that looks for workouts from my main app and watch app bundle IDs.